# Fetch data only if field contains any lower case in the string

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to fetch data with condition "get data only if string contains the lower char in the 4th and 5th position".
Below are the conditions:

```
and ascii(substr(RAP01.CRDVER,4,1)) between 97 and 122
and ascii(substr(RAP01.CRDVER,5,1)) between 97 and 122;
```

Table name RAP01 and column name CRDVER.

But It is not fetching all the required data.
Can this approach is correct?

Comment: Easy condition: `data <> upper(data)` If `true` means they are lowercase in data.

Comment: Please post some sample data which you think the query should return but doesn't.

Comment: That's a good approach using `ascii` function for your case. ( already chr(97)-> 'a' and chr(122)->'z' ).

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, I guess ascii is not a goo approach. Check my answer for discussion :)

Comment: @daniherrera nice, you're right +1

Comment: @daniherrera but I need to specify the position of the char as well, like in my case 4th or 5th.

Comment: @KaushalTalniya nothing wrong with your substring. Just use it.

Comment: @daniherrera Thanks.....

Answer (score 2):

How about this? The *key* is line 8 - query will return strings whose 4th and 5th character (`substr(col, 4, 2)`)is a lowercase letter (`[a-z]`) (`c` means that the *search* is case sensitive).

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '12Bcfx23' from dual union all
  3     select '123456'   from dual union all
  4     select 'ABCDEFGH' from dual
  5    )
  6  select col, substr(col, 4, 2) sub
  7  from test
  8  where regexp_like(substr(col, 4, 2), '[a-z]', 'c');

COL      SU
-------- --
12Bcfx23 cf

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Are lower case a subset of ASCII? **NO**
- Can I use ASCII to identify lower case? **NO**

How can I know if a string has lower case? It has lower case if `UPPER of string` is not the same as just the `string`.

[Sample](https://rextester.com/discussion/OVY41334/checking-for-lower-case):

```
create table t1 ( a varchar(100) )\\

insert into t1 (a) values ( 'A' )\\
insert into t1 (a) values ( 'a' )\\
insert into t1 (a) values ( 'å' )\\
insert into t1 (a) values ( 'æ' )\\

select (case when a = upper( a )                  <-- compare with upper
        then a || ' Is Upper' 
        else a || ' Has lower' end) as r_upper,

       (case when not regexp_like(a, '[a-z]', 'c') <-- using ascii
        then a || ' Is Upper' 
        else a || ' Has lower' end) as r_reg

       from t1\\

R_UPPER     | R_REG 
-------------------------
A Is Upper  | A Is Upper
a Has lower | a Has lower
å Has lower | å Is Upper (¹)
æ Has lower | æ Is Upper (¹)
```

(¹) Wrong result using ASCII.